# adding extra row in django inline template

Tags: python, django, admin, inline

I have theses model and admin model as displayed beloy

I want in the model for transaction to display total amount ( thats is the sum of amount field)

There is not method for change list in Inline how do I do this

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TransactionAmountInline, AmountPaidInline, PhotosInline]
    fields = ('customer', 'title', 'description', 'created_at')
    readonly_fields = ('updated_at',)
    list_display = ('title', 'customer')


class AmountPaidInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = AmountPaid
   extra = 0


class AmountPaid(models.Model):
     transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transactions)
     description = models.TextField(null=True)
     amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this function to your Transactions model.

```
def sum_amount (self):
    return AmountPaid.objects.filter(transaction=self).aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total']
```

And add the function name to the list_display option of TransactionAdmin, the model admin:

```
list_display = ('title', 'customer', 'sum_amount')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer    actually what I what I want is to display the sum_amount in the change form( when you click on the transaction link) I know I can override the change list view to and add the total amount to the extra context but I want to display the total amount in the AmountPaidInline form that its going to be displayed

Comment: In simple I want to add another row to the inline to display the total amount in the AmountPaind model

Comment: please give me more help in this